# Problems With Runnable jar

Tags: java, jar, command-prompt, executable-jar

Hi i have Created a Runnable Jar through Eclipse,there are many system.out.println in my program,i want to make them visible to the user.please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a batch file that makes the `java -jar myJar.jar` call.  That should leave a console window open that will display your output.

The alternative is to create a simple GUI with a `JTextArea` that you can append your logging statements to so the user can see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the JAR from the console using java -jar my jar.jar you will see your `sysout's`.

If you want to execute it by double-click you'll need to create a `JFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can implement loggers for this and write the logs in a file (current directory)

check log4j or simple java logger

Comment: i want to show some messages to the user on command prompt kind of thing when he double clicks the jar

Comment: You want to give some select options ? like 1. add , 2. sub ?

Comment: Yes,i want to give some options too